# Relation does not exist error using WITH

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would greatly appreciate my help. I think this is the last challenge keeping me from finishing a week long project.

My error: Amazon Invalid operation: relation "rentdotcomonly" does not exist;

My code:

```
WITH 
RentDotComOnly AS
(
  SELECT 
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "rent_count_clean_zip", 
    -- AVG((low_price+high_price)/2) AS "rent_avg_price", 
    0.85*min(low_price) AS "rent_lower_bound", 
    1.15*max(high_price) AS "rent_upper_bound"
  FROM 
    archived_apartments 
  WHERE 
    source_type in (29,36,316) 
    AND week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12' 
    AND is_house <> 1  
    AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
  GROUP BY monthlyzip
),
AllRJData AS
(
  SELECT
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "all_count_clean_zip"
    --, AVG((low_price+high_price)/2) AS "all_avg_price"
  FROM 
    archived_apartments 
  WHERE 
    week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12' 
    AND is_house <> 1  
  GROUP BY monthlyzip
),
TrueComps AS
(
  SELECT
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "true_comps"
   FROM
    archived_apartments
   WHERE
    week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12' 
    AND is_house <> 1 
    AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
    AND archived_apartments.low_price > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound
    AND archived_apartments.low_price < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound
    OR
    week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12' 
    AND is_house <> 1 
    AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
    AND archived_apartments.high_price > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound
    AND archived_apartments.high_price < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound
)

SELECT 
  distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
  RentDotComOnly.rent_count_clean_zip AS "RentComOnly",
  AllRJData.all_count_clean_zip AS "Total",
  TrueComps.true_comps AS "TrueComps"
FROM
  archived_apartments 
JOIN AllRJData 
ON concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartments.clean_zip) = AllRJData.monthlyzip
JOIN RentDotComOnly
ON concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartments.clean_zip) = RentDotComOnly.monthlyzip
JOIN TrueComps
ON concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartments.clean_zip) = TrueComps.monthlyzip

GROUP BY AllRJData.monthlyzip
ORDER BY AllRJData.monthlyzip
```

Comment: @MorganThrapp: not that's not required - the column names will be determined by column names of the inner query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Gotcha, I thought you did for some reason.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't keep editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Mutated Problem

Question has mutated.  It is not yet clear to me what the revised problem is.

#### Original Problem

The original error was:

```
 [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "rentdotcomonly" does not exist;
```

In the original definition of `TrueComps`, you had:

```
TrueComps AS
(
  SELECT
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "true_comps"
   FROM
    archived_apartments
   WHERE
    week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12' 
    AND is_house <> 1 
    AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
    AND archived_apartments.low_price > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound
    AND archived_apartments.low_price < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound
```

You've not used `RentDotComOnly` in the FROM clause.  You will need to list it for it to be defined in this CTE.

Comment: same error persists after modifying FROM to:
  archived_apartments, RentDotComOnly, TrueComps

Comment: If you have `FROM archived_apartments, RentDotComOnly, TrueComps` in the definition of `TrueComps` , then you probably get a variant of the error message citing `TrueComps` now instead of `RentDotComOnly`.  You should also review whether the comma list is appropriate or whether you can use the JOIN notation.

Comment: I was dumb and edited the wrong FROM. Your feedback makes sense now. Thank you but I got a new error causing me to believe that my approach might be off. Updating my code in the question.

Comment: Please don't make your question into a 'chameleon question'.  You've got a wholly different problem now.  You could add a new query, leaving the original.  You should also learn how to run the queries standalone, debugging each one in turn.  Search for TDQD in SO to see my views on the subject of test-driven query design — something that should be applied to a query of this complexity.